# Android Theme : Can't see the letters

Tags: android, android-theme

Lately i've styling my android app but it seems like the style has been changed and suddelny i can't see the letters that i write in some fields.

Pictures :

[image: input form images]

and even the buttons arent that clear :

[image: image buttons]

AndroidManisfest file :

```
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Style1" >
```

Style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- File created by the Android Action Bar Style Generator

     Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
     Copyright (C) 2012 readyState Software Ltd

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Style1" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_style1</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Style1</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Style1</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Style1</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Style1</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Transparent.Style1</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_style1</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_style1</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Style1</item>


    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Style1" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_style1</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_style1</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_style1</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Style1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Style1" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_style1</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Style1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.Style1" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_style1</item>    
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.Style1" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_style1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Style1" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_style1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.Style1" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_style1</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_style1</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_style1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar.Style1" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_style1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Style1" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_style1</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Style1.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Style1</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Style1</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

For My activty ,i have tried these values : 
"@android:style/Theme.Holo" = still the same
"@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" = it changed to what i need but the action bar changed too

what can i do to change them to normal ?

Comment: post your custom theme? In every <activity> you can add a theme, check if there activities have this attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with

```
 Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar?
```

seems like would fit your design and it comes with dark text_color by default

Comment: I have added that to my activites and it works perfectly,thank you